# MS Access 2007 - After importing tables, recordsets are no longer updateable

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have an in-house program at the company I work for, and inside of MS Access we link all of our tables to our three databases.  However; in order to create new routes for students, someone needs an isolated copy of our program to work with that won't impact the actual database.

After deleting the linked tables, importing them all locally, and saving the .mdb I can no longer change values inside of most forms.  For example:

A drop down menu with a list of possible route codes for a student will appear.  Usually you can select one.  You are no longer able to, and in the bottom left hand corner you see "this recordset is not updateable".

I'm a bit new at this, but I can't imagine why importing the tables would break anything.  I wouldn't expect any key violations to occur (like I might when linking tables), or anything of that nature.  If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: So, you have a backend database that supplies the tables for 3 front end databases and you copied one of the front ends and imported all of the backend tables to a local copy of the front end?

Comment: Check for permissions issues and that the tables maintained their primary keys. Is there any VBA (code) that could lock the forms/controls? Is Locked = True in the properties of that combobox? Allow edits?

Comment: When you imported the tables locally, did you add a primary key?

Comment: In regard to your first comment: correct.  How can I check for permissions issues?  I'm not notified of any.  I'm online searching right now, but if you have a link as a reference to share I'd appreciate that.  I'm checking the primary keys as we speak. @mellamokb No I did not.

Comment: There are no primary keys found in the imported tables.  I re-added the primary keys for the tables with a PK for only a single column.  For the tables with multiple PKs (or maybe they were foreign keys?) I could not add primary keys to those columns.  Not too sure where to go from here.  The programmer just left the company, and I have little knowledge of access as a whole (though I'll definitely be picking up a book today).  I'm just stumbling around trying to patch this up so they can have it done by the New Year.  And again, I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: You can add multiple-column primary keys in Access.  I believe most of the time errors updating records is because of missing primary keys or too complex joins/queries - this is because Access is unable to uniquely identify a row for updating.

Comment: ^^^^^ .. It's most likely that or a Permissions issue.

Comment: Well, I checked, double-checked, and then triple-checked.  Indeed, in the back end there are multiple primary keys.  In access, if I select the necessary columns, and then add a primary key and save, I get this error:  The changes you requested to teh table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in teh index, PK, or relationship.  Change the data in the field(s) that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and then try again.  Could the last sentence be they key here?  The columns are text (varchar) fields.

Comment: That sounds very suspicious.  You didn't perhaps import twice and get two copies of the data or something like that?  Is the back-end data source you referred to originally another MS Access database, or another database system entirely (like SQL Server, etc.)?  If the back-end is MS Access, it seems like there should be a way to import the table objects directly and maintain the design schema.  How exactly did you copy the data local from the backend database?

Comment: It's an SQL back end, so unfortunately there probably isn't a way to import and maintain the design schema (unless anyone has some sage advice).  I imported them from inside of MS Access by deleting the linked tables, and then importing from an ODBC data source, selecting the database, and then the tables in question.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a copy of the SQL back end instead and link to that temporarily?  Then you could easily copy the data back to the original source once the offline changes have been made?

Answer (score 0):

Access can handle a compound primary key on a linked table or view. The important thing, of course, is to make sure you're telling Access the right fields to use. It's common for Access not to get the primary key info when you're linking to a view (perhaps the ODBC driver doesn't pass that info along?), but I bet it can happen with tables too.
Not sure if these pics will help, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction. Here's a linked view, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

If you open it in design view, you can see that there are no primary keys:

[image]

which means that the table isn't editable (the add new button is greyed out):

[image]

So I run this command to tell Access to use a compound primary key on the linked view:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Create Unique Index PrimaryKey On View_AssnsWithSorterField([Serial No], AssignmentDate)"
```

If you open the linked view in design view again, you can see the compound primary key:

[image]

and now the add new button appears.

[image]

You said that you tried to add a compound primary key but Access wouldn't allow it, which sounds like there's something about the table's data or structure that prevents it from using that key. How about creating an empty copy of the table in the backend database, then try linking to that? If that still doesn't work then maybe there's a unique constraint, or a trigger, or something else on the table that causes Access not to like making it updateable. Conversely, if it links fine and you can add/edit records in the linked blank test table, then it must be *data* in the real table that's causing the issue.
Sometimes if you cut down a copy of the table into smaller chunks (like maybe just start with the primary key columns alone) and gradually rebuild it piece by piece, you eventually hit on the thing that makes Access not let it be updateable.

One other possibility, of course, is a problem with the driver itself. The ODBC drivers that link to SQLServer and Oracle are good quality and can handle complex primary keys, but I've used junky drivers that link to obscure databases and they couldn't handle complex things like subqueries, union queries, etc, even though you could do those things in the database itself; the driver was only written to handle basic select/insert/update/deletes and that was it.